# Eventlistener on button to display div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

Need to display a div when the user clicks the button.

//html-code

```
      <div class="col-md-4">
          <h4 class="service-heading">Sociala Medier</h4>
          <p class="text-muted">first line of text.</p>
            <div class="info-text" style="display:none">
              <p class="text-muted">Second line of text.</p>
            </div>
          <button class="info-button"><span>Läs mer </span></button>
        </div>
```

//js-code

```
document.getElementByClassName("info-button").addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementByClassName('info-text').style.display = "block";
});
```

Any advice how I can get this to work? Also tested with onclick but that doesn't work either.

Comment: `<div class="info-text" ` and `document.getElementById('info-text')` does not match up, same as the button `<button class="info-button">` these are classes, not id

Comment: Copied old version, tried with getElementByClassName as well and doesn't work. Updated my post.

Comment: can you try:  **document.querySelector(".info-button")** This will work only if there is only one element with that class

Comment: Did you mean https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName `getElementsByClassName` you missed a `s`. Check my answer for example

Answer (score 0):

You're passing elements classes to the `.getElementById` function. 
In short, you could change your HTML to this:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
  <h4 class="service-heading">Sociala Medier</h4>
  <p class="text-muted">first line of text.</p>
  <div id="info-text" style="display:none">
    <p class="text-muted">Second line of text.</p>
  </div>
  <button id="info-button"><span>Läs mer </span></button>
</div>
```

And it would work

Comment: Sorry guys, copied wrong version to my question. Tried with getElementsByClassName but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually "getElementsByClassName" you missed the `s` and it gets a collection so you need to be specific on which one you are targeting. Given your code, you want the first/only element

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

https://jsfiddle.net/cbye0ph9/

```
document.getElementsByClassName("info-button")[0].addEventListener("click", function(){
   document.getElementsByClassName('info-text')[0].style.display = "block";
});
```

Comment: Thanks Huangism! Really appreciate your help.